# Why will this not return the average of 1-5?

Tags: python, function, average

```
def avg(n):
    count=0
    sum=0
    for var in range(n):
        count+=1
        sum+=var
    return (sum/count)
print (avg(5))
```

This is an attempt at using a for loop to find the average of the integers from 1 up to n..
What am I missing?

Comment: language? and indentation pleeease ;)

Comment: What are the results you're getting, 2 instead of 2.5?

Comment: You just need to tag this post as python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two reasons. First you sum numbers from 0..4 (inclusively). You can fix it by doing `range(1,n+1)`, or change to `sum += var + 1`

Second reason is that integer division is used by default, you can enforce float division by adding to the top:

```
from __future__ import division
```

or doing locally `return sum/float(count)`

Comment: Judging from the syntax, user2737592 is already in the future, no need for the division import. Not that it would be noticeable in the example anyway, since the result is 3.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida yeah, possible, that's why it is reason number 2, if the first one doesn't help. I had only python 2.7 at hand.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the doc:

> **range(start, stop[, step])**
>
> If the start argument is omitted, it defaults to 0. The full form
>   returns a list of plain integers [start, start + step, start + 2 *
>   step, ...]. If step is positive, the last element is the largest start
>   + i * step **less than stop**;

In other words, `range()` is non-inclusive in Python. And that means you have off-by-one error in your code, that's how it should look like:

```
def avg(n):
    count=0
    sum=0
    for var in range(1, n+1):
        count+=1
        sum+=var
    return (float(sum)/count)
print (avg(5))
```